# Converting Index to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

After renaming a column, the dataset has converted into a pandas.core.indexes.base.Index. I want to convert df4 to a dataframe, but keep getting error messages.
[image: problem v1]

[image: problem v2]

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the result of the function call `pd.DataFrame()` to the variable `df4`.

Try this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(rating_df)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df3.columns.str.replace("anime_id", "MAL_ID")
df4.head()
```

This will print out your index as a dataframe.